# Error 1136 column count doesnt match value count

Tags: mysql

```
create table babumon_salary 
(
  Name varchar (10) not null,
  Salary int not null
);

INSERT into babumon_salary ( Name , Salary)
values ((  'baabumonji' , 2000),
         ( 'ayyapanjip' , 3000 ),
         ( 'daniyomary' , 4000 ),
         ( 'kundanmaro' , 5000 ))
```

I'm getting error 1136 column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in my sql when I try to run this query.

Answer (score 2):

Remove 2 parentheses:

```
INSERT into babumon_salary (Name, Salary)
values ('baabumonji', 2000),
       ('ayyapanjip', 3000),
       ('daniyomary', 4000),
       ('kundanmaro', 5000)
```